# Engine Light on 2008 Kia Rondo

Tags: engine, kia, warning-light

I have a 2008 Kia rondo 2.7 V6. My check engine light came on for spark plugs. I went ahead and changed all 6 and it still came back for a misfire in cylinder 1 and said it was still the spark plug. I swapped ignition coils with a new one to see if it was the problem but now it says the cause is both the ignition coil and the spark plug in cylinder one.

Comment: How did it tell you that the spark plugs and ignition coil is at fault?  Was it by fault codes?  If so, tell us the codes, please.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already replaced the spark plugs and did the ignition coil swap, the list of remaining causes is still rather long. It could be any of the following:

- Faulty fuel injector
- Low fuel pressure
- Vacuum leak
- Faulty camshaft or crankshaft sensor
- Low compression in cylinder 1
- Leaking head gasket near cylinder 1

To diagnose the above requires special equipment and expertise. Depending on your skill level and tool supply you can diagnosis this yourself or take it to a highly rated independent mechanic to diagnosis the cause.

Comment: This is a good list, but because the fault is isolated to one cylinder I would do a compression test first to eliminate serious engine damage. Next move to fuel injector. Fuel pressure and vacuum leak usually affects more than one cylinder.